# Firing a OnSelectedIndexChanged event within code

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

As well as this event firing from the drop down, I would also like to be able to fire it from my code. Is this possible and if so how?

Thanks

Stu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to do this is to wrap the code from the event into a method, and call it from both places.

**BUT** if you did want to call the event directly (which I don't recommend), you can do it like this:

```
MyComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(null, null);
```

(Unless you use either the `sender` or `EventArgs` within the method, then you will need to supply these too)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fire the `SelectedIndexChanged` event from code you could either call the event handler like `CmbBox_SelectedIndexChanged(null, null);` or do

```
   if(CmbBox.SelectedIndex <> index)//let index is a int variable
      CmbBox.SelectedIndex = index;       
   else
   {
      CmbBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
      CmbBox.SelectedIndex = index;
   }
```

Comment: CmbBox.SelectedIndex = index; will only fire the event if the index has changed